# How to make a mirror of Linux Mint package repository with debmirror?

Tags: linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint 12 Lisa and for some reason want to have local packages repository. I've done local copies before on Ubuntu and it was easy. But unlike Ubuntu's archive.ubuntu.com, packages.linuxmint.com is a webpage, not directory listing. So I'm stuck...  What mirroring command should look like? Sample below.

```
debmirror -p -v --method=rsync --dist=lisa --root=??? -a=amd64 --nosource --host=packages.linuxmint.com --section=main,upstream,import ~/mirror/lisa
```

Comment: Does Linux Mint have packages now that are specific to it? I thought that they just used the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: For example, they have Cinnamon. I'm mirroring Ubuntu's  reps too. Just have a problem with Mint only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
debmirror -p -v --method=http --dist=lisa --root=. -a=amd64 --nosource --host=packages.linuxmint.com --section=main,upstream,import ~/mirror/lisa
```

'.' as root and http instead rsync did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using any of the following urls

```
packages.linuxmint.com/pool

packages.linuxmint.com/pool/backport/   
packages.linuxmint.com/pool/community/  
packages.linuxmint.com/pool/envizions/  
packages.linuxmint.com/pool/import/ 
packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/   
packages.linuxmint.com/pool/romeo/  
packages.linuxmint.com/pool/upstream/
```

I think those might work better for you but you'll have to choose which one you want to use because I think they all have different stability ratings.